# How to Clear Firefox Cache and Cookies from .VBS or Bat

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

Hello I want to clear Firefox cookies + cache from .vbs script or bat , i already have tried ccleaner /auto but the thing is it needs browser to be closed for clearing cache and cookies else it skips it , i would like to clear cookies and cache without closing the browser from either .vbs script or .bat script can you please give the code or recommend any other method ?

thanks

Comment: try this: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/sourcecode.php?src=ffxcac_nt

Answer (score 0):

Enduros answer might help,however here is a short way of doing it if you have ccleaner installed you can call the ccleaner comaandline `ccsetup.exe /S`  or use other various parameter options to do whatever specific task you might be interested here is a link to there comandline options [ccleaner commandline parameters](http://www.piriform.com/docs/ccleaner/advanced-usage/command-line-parameters) you would also use the folling sniplet

```
#include <File.au3>

Dim $sPath = @AppDataDir & '\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles'

Dim $arr = _FileListToArray($sPath, '*.default', 2)

If IsArray($arr) Then
For $i = 1 To $arr[0]
    FileDelete($sPath & "\" & $arr[$i] & "\cookies.sqlite")
Next
EndIf
```